# Installing GRASS on MINT 14?

Tags: grass-gis, installation, linux

I'm very new to mint/linux/GRASS and have no clue how to deal with these errors.  Can I just change the URL somewhere?

Here is the simplest reproducible command to produce a failure:
    sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5

Here is the output from my attempt to run/install grass:

```
mint@mint ~ $ grass
The program 'grass' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install grass-core
mint@mint ~ $ sudo apt-get install grass-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gdal-bin libarmadillo3 libdap11 libdapclient3 libepsilon0 libfreexl1
  libgdal1 libgeos-3.3.3 libgeos-c1 libgfortran3 libhdf4-0-alt libhdf5-7
  liblapack3 libmysqlclient18 libnetcdfc7 libodbc1 libogdi3.2 libpq5 libproj0
  libspatialite3 libxerces-c28 mysql-common odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 proj-bin
  proj-data python-numpy
Suggested packages:
  python-gdal grass-doc grass-gui grass-dev e00compr avce00 gnuplot gpsbabel
  gpstrans netpbm python-rpy2 xml2 libhdf4-doc libhdf4-alt-dev hdf4-tools
  libnetcdf4 libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc unixodbc-bin ogdi-bin
  proj-ps-doc python-numpy-doc python-numpy-dbg python-nose python-dev
  gfortran
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gdal-bin grass-core libarmadillo3 libdap11 libdapclient3 libepsilon0
  libfreexl1 libgdal1 libgeos-3.3.3 libgeos-c1 libgfortran3 libhdf4-0-alt
  libhdf5-7 liblapack3 libmysqlclient18 libnetcdfc7 libodbc1 libogdi3.2 libpq5
  libproj0 libspatialite3 libxerces-c28 mysql-common odbcinst odbcinst1debian2
  proj-bin proj-data python-numpy
0 upgraded, 28 newly installed, 0 to remove and 130 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,043 kB/33.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 94.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main mysql-common all 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main libpq5 amd64 9.1.6-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main mysql-common all 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main libmysqlclient18 amd64 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-common_5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/libmysqlclient18_5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-9.1/libpq5_9.1.6-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
mint@mint ~ $
```

Comment: sudo apt-get update<br/>
sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to update my package definitions and upgrade my packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```